# Find all indexes of a value in a List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to search an `ArrayList` for a user input. I've managed to create a search that prints the index of the first occurrence from within the list.

I'm having trouble trying to get the rest of the indexes that the item are stored.

Here is the code I have got so far to print the first index of `search`:

```java
if (names.contains(search)) {
    System.out.println("name found!");
    System.out.println(names.indexOf(search));
}
```

I understand that a loop needs to be added. But I am having trouble trying to formulate it.

#### Example

```java
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Bob");
names.add("Jerry");
names.add("Bob"); 
names.add("Mick");
```

Say `search = "Bob"`.  My expected result would be `{0,2}`.  Instead, I am only able to get the index of the first occurrence (`0`).

```java
assert allIndexesOf(names, "Bob").equals(List.of(0, 2));

[...]

private List<Integer> allIndexesOf(List<?> list, Object o) {
  // How can this be implemented?
}
```

How can I get all indexes that match the search string?

Comment: Forget programming for a while. Imagine you have 10 drawers, numbered from 0 to 9, and want to find all the drawers containing a blue sheet of paper, and write their number on a sheet of paper. How do you do?

Comment: Okay - seems like a school assignment, so I will be very high level to help with the logic.

for all items in the list, if the item at the current index is what I'm looking for, then add to a different list the index, else don't do anything and move on

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]). - You have done all that, nice!

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The "duplicate" question is about characters within a string, not elements within a list.  While they have similar APIs, they are not identical.  Further, there are other solutions (e.g. streams) that may be more appropriate than `indexOf` for Lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

The method `List#indexOf` only returns the index of the **first** found matching element. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. [...]

But you want **all**, therefore you also need to **iterate all elements**.

Also note that calling `List#contains` is not necessary since `List#indexOf` also answers this question, it returns `-1` if not found. In fact in an `ArrayList` both calls are very **expensive** (they iterate from left to right until found) so you shouldn't use unnecessary statements if they are such expensive.

---

### Solution

Instead just iterate all elements and collect the ones that match:

```
ArrayList<String> author = ...
String needle = ...

// Collect matches
List<Integer> matchingIndices = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < author.size(); i++) {
    String element = author.get(i);

    if (needle.equals(element)) {
        matchingIndices.add(i);
    }
}

// Print matches
matchingIndices.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you may use some of the very convenient methods of the **Stream API**. `Stream#filter` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)) for example:

```
List<Integer> matchingIndices = IntStream.range(0, author.size())
    .filter(i -> needle.equals(author.get(i))) // Only keep those indices
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to start from first index of occurrence of item rather than from 0th position?

Comment: @CoolCloud Sure, if you know that index beforehand already... but if your suggesting to use something like `indexOf`, you are not really gaining anything. Since that method will also just simply iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You could go over the entire list and save all the indexes that match the search term. Java 8's steams give you a pretty elegant way of doing this:

```
int[] indexes =
    IntStream.range(0, names.size())
             .filter(i -> names.get(i).equals(search))
             .toArray();
```

Comment: But then he looses the indices. I think he wants to collect the indices, not the elements (since they are equal).

Comment: @Zabuza you should read my solution again - it does collect the indexes.

Comment: In the present form, I think this is a poor question. As JB Nizet said, there's a bigger question to be tackled here.

Comment: Ah indeed, thought you had done a `map` and thus loosing track of the indices.

Comment: @S.R.I I think it's a fine question.  I actually had this come up today in a decidedly non-homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0;i<author.size();i++){
  if(author.get(i).equals(searchTerm)) {
    System.out.println("Author found!");
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid comparing `String` with `==`. The result is probably not what you expected. Exchange it with `String#equals` and it will be fine.

Comment: More on this [SO: How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited my post.